# How it works ResponseBody and what it returns

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-boot, controller

I have a problem. The thing is that @Reponsebody return the HTML DOM, but i dont want this. But if i remove the response body it return an error in the controller. 
Here is the controller:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/isvoted")
public @ResponseBody List<Boolean> isvoted() {

    Authentication auth= SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails)auth.getPrincipal();
    Usuario usuario = (Usuario)usuarioService.findByUsername(userDetails.getUsername());
    Long id = usuario.getId();

    List<Tapas> tapas = tapaService.findAllTapas();
    List<Boolean> listavotos = new ArrayList<Boolean>();

    for (Tapas tapa : tapas) {
        if (voteService.selectVoteByUserAndTapa(id, tapa.getId()) != null) {
            listavotos.add(true);
        }else {
            listavotos.add(false);
        }
    }
    return listavotos;
```

So, the method return a list of booleans and ajax get the reponse, but the reponse also return the body of the html, how can i implement for returning only the listavotos (list of boolean) without including the body of the HTML.

this is my ajax get request:

```
const full = $('input[name="voto"]').attr("value", "\uf004").css({"font-family": "'Font Awesome 5 Free'"});

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/isvoted",
        success: function(result) {

            if (result === undefined || result.length == 0){
                console.log("no hay votos");
            }else{
                for (var voto of result) {
                  if(voto === true){
                      console.log("voto true");
                      full.css({"font-weight": "900"});
                  }else{
                      console.log("voto false");
                      full.css({"font-weight": ''});
                  }
                }
            }

        },
        error: function(result) {
            console.log("error");
        }
    });
```

To resume, when the document is ready, it is called the ajax get request for kwnowing if theres votes, if there are votes it return the list of boolean (response), that it gets it from the controller isvoted, but also return the reponsebody (the html body), but i dont want this. I want that the controller only return the list to kwnow if an element it voted, and if its voted to have an css style, if isn voted, to have another style. Really thankfull for your help. If you need more information just posted and i will clarify.

the full controller (is not a restcontroller):

```
@Controller
```

public class VoteController {

```
@Autowired
private IVoteService voteService;

@Autowired
private IUsuarioService usuarioService;

@Autowired
private ITapasService tapaService;

private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

@GetMapping(value = "/isvoted")
@ResponseBody
public List<Boolean> isvoted(@RequestBody List<Boolean> listavotos) {

    Authentication auth= SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails)auth.getPrincipal();
    Usuario usuario = (Usuario)usuarioService.findByUsername(userDetails.getUsername());
    Long id = usuario.getId();

    List<Tapas> tapas = tapaService.findAllTapas();
    listavotos = new ArrayList<Boolean>();

    for (Tapas tapa : tapas) {
        if (voteService.selectVoteByUserAndTapa(id, tapa.getId()) != null) {
            listavotos.add(true);
        }else {
            listavotos.add(false);
        }
    }
    return listavotos;

}

@PostMapping(value = "/votecreate")
public String guardar(@Valid Vote vote, BindingResult result, Model model,
        @RequestParam(name = "tapa", required = true) Tapas tapa,
        RedirectAttributes flash, SessionStatus status) {

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        List<ObjectError> errors = result.getAllErrors();
        for(ObjectError error : errors) {
            System.out.println("This is the error: " +error);
        }
        return "redirect:/home";
    }

    //String mensajeFlash = (vote.getId() != null) ? "voto quitado con con exito" : "votado con exito!";

    Authentication auth= SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails)auth.getPrincipal();
    Usuario usuario = (Usuario)usuarioService.findByUsername(userDetails.getUsername());

    //Tapas tapa = tapaService.findTapaById(Long.parseLong(tapaid));

    vote.setTapa(tapa);
    vote.setUsuario(usuario);

    voteService.save(vote);
    status.setComplete();
    //flash.addFlashAttribute("success", mensajeFlash);

    return "redirect:/home";
}

@GetMapping(value = "/votedelete/{tapaId}")
public String eliminar(@PathVariable(value = "tapaId") Long tapaId, RedirectAttributes flash) {

    //Tapas tapa = tapaService.findTapaById(tapaId);

    Authentication auth= SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails)auth.getPrincipal();
    Usuario usuario = (Usuario)usuarioService.findByUsername(userDetails.getUsername());
    Long userId = usuario.getId();
    log.debug("Usuario id:", userId);

    if (userId != null && tapaId != null) {

        Vote vote = voteService.selectVoteByUserAndTapa(userId, tapaId);
        log.debug("vote:", vote.getId());
        voteService.delete(vote.getId());
        flash.addFlashAttribute("success", "Voto eliminado con exito");

        return "redirect:/home/";
    }

    flash.addFlashAttribute("error", "El bar no existe en la base de datos");
    return "redirect:/bares/";
}
```

}

Comment: Could you add the whole Controller class?

Comment: Try to add this line in ajax call, `dataType: "json",` @Ismael

Comment: its like when on the app i am not login, the auth user parameter passed to the vote.repository on the controller, it return the HTML DOM, because there is not auth user for getting the id, but then i create and logged a user it seems it works and return a list of boolen. what should i do? for no return the HTML when there is no user logged

Answer (score 0):

The thing was that when in the controller on the mapping /isvoted the jQuery can be execute when the user is logged (it get auth details) and exists tapas (get id of the tapas), because the query of the repository can be made successfully but when a user isn't logged, it returns a string of the layout of thymeleaf, so I just only add a condition for knowing if the return of the controller is a string(DOM of the thymelead) and not a list of bool it console log a message that a user is not authenticated so there is not option for showing the result (list of booleans)

```
if (result === undefined || result.length == 0)
    console.log("no hay votos");
else if (typeof(result) == "string")
    console.log("you are not logger, you should be logged to see the VOTES");
else
    for (var voto of result) {
        console.log(result);

        if (voto === true) {
            full.prop('disabled', true);
            console.log(voto);
        } else {
            full.prop('disabled', false);
            console.log(voto);
        }
    }
```